# Problem with reading data from HMC5883L in GY-86

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I am trying to read the data from GY-86 with my arduino UNO.
While reading MPU6050 and MS5611, it works quite well. But somehow I can't read anything from HMC5883L. Here is the code I used:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HMC5883L.h>

HMC5883L compass;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize HMC5883L
  Serial.println("Initialize HMC5883L");
  while (!compass.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid HMC5883L sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }

  // Set measurement range
  // +/- 0.88 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_0_88GA
  // +/- 1.30 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA (default)
  // +/- 1.90 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_1_9GA
  // +/- 2.50 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_2_5GA
  // +/- 4.00 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_4GA
  // +/- 4.70 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_4_7GA
  // +/- 5.60 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_5_6GA
  // +/- 8.10 Ga: HMC5883L_RANGE_8_1GA
  compass.setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);

  // Set measurement mode
  // Idle mode:              HMC5883L_IDLE
  // Single-Measurement:     HMC5883L_SINGLE
  // Continuous-Measurement: HMC5883L_CONTINOUS (default)
  compass.setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);

  // Set data rate
  //  0.75Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_0_75HZ
  //  1.50Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_1_5HZ
  //  3.00Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_3HZ
  //  7.50Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_7_50HZ
  // 15.00Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_15HZ (default)
  // 30.00Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_30HZ
  // 75.00Hz: HMC5883L_DATARATE_75HZ
  compass.setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_15HZ);

  // Set number of samples averaged
  // 1 sample:  HMC5883L_SAMPLES_1 (default)
  // 2 samples: HMC5883L_SAMPLES_2
  // 4 samples: HMC5883L_SAMPLES_4
  // 8 samples: HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8
  compass.setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_1);

  // Check settings
  checkSettings();
}

void checkSettings()
{
  Serial.print("Selected range: ");

  switch (compass.getRange())
  {
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_0_88GA: Serial.println("0.88 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA:  Serial.println("1.3 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_1_9GA:  Serial.println("1.9 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_2_5GA:  Serial.println("2.5 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_4GA:    Serial.println("4 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_4_7GA:  Serial.println("4.7 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_5_6GA:  Serial.println("5.6 Ga"); break;
    case HMC5883L_RANGE_8_1GA:  Serial.println("8.1 Ga"); break;
    default: Serial.println("Bad range!");
  }

  Serial.print("Selected Measurement Mode: ");
  switch (compass.getMeasurementMode())
  {  
    case HMC5883L_IDLE: Serial.println("Idle mode"); break;
    case HMC5883L_SINGLE:  Serial.println("Single-Measurement"); break;
    case HMC5883L_CONTINOUS:  Serial.println("Continuous-Measurement"); break;
    default: Serial.println("Bad mode!");
  }

  Serial.print("Selected Data Rate: ");
  switch (compass.getDataRate())
  {  
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_0_75_HZ: Serial.println("0.75 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_1_5HZ:  Serial.println("1.5 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_3HZ:  Serial.println("3 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_7_5HZ: Serial.println("7.5 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_15HZ:  Serial.println("15 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_30HZ: Serial.println("30 Hz"); break;
    case HMC5883L_DATARATE_75HZ:  Serial.println("75 Hz"); break;
    default: Serial.println("Bad data rate!");
  }

  Serial.print("Selected number of samples: ");
  switch (compass.getSamples())
  {  
    case HMC5883L_SAMPLES_1: Serial.println("1"); break;
    case HMC5883L_SAMPLES_2: Serial.println("2"); break;
    case HMC5883L_SAMPLES_4: Serial.println("4"); break;
    case HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8: Serial.println("8"); break;
    default: Serial.println("Bad number of samples!");
  }

}

void loop()
{
  Vector raw = compass.readRaw();
  Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

  Serial.print(" Xraw = ");
  Serial.print(raw.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Yraw = ");
  Serial.print(raw.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" Zraw = ");
  Serial.print(raw.ZAxis);
  Serial.print(" Xnorm = ");
  Serial.print(norm.XAxis);
  Serial.print(" Ynorm = ");
  Serial.print(norm.YAxis);
  Serial.print(" ZNorm = ");
  Serial.print(norm.ZAxis);
  Serial.println();  

  delay(100);
}
```

I download it from https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-HMC5883L.

The program always stuck at

```
  while (!compass.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid HMC5883L sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }
```

Here is the begin function in HMC5883L.cpp

```
bool HMC5883L::begin()
{
    Wire.begin();

    if ((fastRegister8(HMC5883L_REG_IDENT_A) != 0x48)
    || (fastRegister8(HMC5883L_REG_IDENT_B) != 0x34)
    || (fastRegister8(HMC5883L_REG_IDENT_C) != 0x33))
    {
    return false;
    }

    setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);
    setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);
    setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_15HZ);
    setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_1);

    mgPerDigit = 0.92f;

    return true;
}
```

So, it seems that the begin function always returns False. What should i do to solve this problem?

This is how I connect GY-86 to UNO:

VCC-IN  -> 5V

GND     -> GND

SDA     -> 4A

SLC     -> 5A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run a i2c scanner? Is it found with i2c address 0x1E?

Looking at the schematic, the magnetometer HMC5883L is connected to XDA and XCL. That is not the normal I2C bus, but a second I2C bus from the MPU-6050.

The reason for that is that the 'dmp' firmware in the MPU-6050 can read the magnetometer and do calculations with it, in the MPU-6050.

If you want to communicate with the magnetormeter via the normal I2C bus, then you have to turn on the bypass-mode.

The libraries from Jeff Rowberg and Jarzębski are large. I suggest to enable the bypass-mode and run a i2c scanner.

Do you have a logic analyzer? 
Perhaps you can use a simple multimeter. Keep the SDA low (shortcut it to GND) and try to measure if XDA is low as well in the bypass mode.

There is a chance that something is broken.

Comment: It might be a problem here.  A i2c scanner only found 0x68 and 0x77. Does it means that my GY-86 is broken?

Comment: By the way, I also try to use the I2Cbypass code in this website
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966638/mpu6050-read-accel-gyro-and-magnetometer)

`mpu.setI2CMasterModeEnabled(false);

mpu.setI2CBypassEnabled(true);

mpu.setSleepEnabled(false);`

But still, it stuck at begin() again.

Comment: You still have to call `mpu.begin` before enabling the bypass. I have added to my answer some background information and how to test the second I2C bus.

Answer (score 3):

Thank to Jot, your answer actually helps me.
Now I am using this code and it is working very well.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <HMC5883L.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

HMC5883L compass;
MPU6050 mpu;

int previousDegree;

void setup()
{
  #if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
        Wire.begin();
  #elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
        Fastwire::setup(400, true);
  #endif
  Serial.begin(38400);

  // Initialize MPU6050
  mpu.initialize();

  // Enable bypass mode
  mpu.setI2CMasterModeEnabled(false);
  mpu.setI2CBypassEnabled(true);
  mpu.setSleepEnabled(false);

  // Initialize HMC5883L
  while (!compass.begin())
  {
    delay(500);
  }

  // Set measurement range
  compass.setRange(HMC5883L_RANGE_1_3GA);

  // Set measurement mode
  compass.setMeasurementMode(HMC5883L_CONTINOUS);

  // Set data rate
  compass.setDataRate(HMC5883L_DATARATE_30HZ);

  // Set number of samples averaged
  compass.setSamples(HMC5883L_SAMPLES_8);

  // Set calibration offset. See HMC5883L_calibration.ino
  compass.setOffset(0, 0); 
}

void loop()
{
  long x = micros();
  Vector norm = compass.readNormalize();

  // Calculate heading
  float heading = atan2(norm.YAxis, norm.XAxis);

  // Set declination angle on your location and fix heading
  // You can find your declination on: http://magnetic-declination.com/
  // (+) Positive or (-) for negative
  // For Bytom / Poland declination angle is 4'26E (positive)
  // Formula: (deg + (min / 60.0)) / (180 / M_PI);
  float declinationAngle = (4.0 + (26.0 / 60.0)) / (180 / M_PI);
  heading += declinationAngle;

  // Correct for heading < 0deg and heading > 360deg
  if (heading < 0)
  {
    heading += 2 * PI;
  }

  if (heading > 2 * PI)
  {
    heading -= 2 * PI;
  }

  // Convert to degrees
  float headingDegrees = heading * 180/M_PI; 

  // Fix HMC5883L issue with angles
  float fixedHeadingDegrees;

  if (headingDegrees >= 1 && headingDegrees < 240)
  {
    fixedHeadingDegrees = map(headingDegrees, 0, 239, 0, 179);
  } else
  if (headingDegrees >= 240)
  {
    fixedHeadingDegrees = map(headingDegrees, 240, 360, 180, 360);
  }

  // Smooth angles rotation for +/- 3deg
  int smoothHeadingDegrees = round(fixedHeadingDegrees);

  if (smoothHeadingDegrees < (previousDegree + 3) && smoothHeadingDegrees > (previousDegree - 3))
  {
    smoothHeadingDegrees = previousDegree;
  }

  previousDegree = smoothHeadingDegrees;

  // Output
  Serial.print(norm.XAxis);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(norm.YAxis);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(norm.ZAxis);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(headingDegrees);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(fixedHeadingDegrees);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(smoothHeadingDegrees);  
  Serial.println();

  // One loop: ~5ms @ 115200 serial.
  // We need delay ~28ms for allow data rate 30Hz (~33ms)
  delay(30);
}
```

By the way, the code on https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-HMC5883L should add

```
  #if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
        Wire.begin();
  #elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
        Fastwire::setup(400, true);
  #endif
```

in the begin of setup.